# NodeJS file system fs - Is it possible to create a file to be downloaded to downloads folder

Tags: node.js, file, fs

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = fs.createWriteStream("my_file.txt");
stream.once('open', function(fd) {
   stream.write("My first row\n");
   stream.write("My second row\n");
   stream.end();
});
```

If I have the code above , how would I go about downloading my_file.txt to a downloads folder on a users device (i.e laptop or mobile device).

So I have chat messages on screen and I want to write them to file the user can download for reference!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, If you have file you can download it as:

```
app.get('/download', function (req, res) {

    var file = 'file_path_goes_here';

    var filename = path.basename(file);
    var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

    var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    filestream.pipe(res);
});
```

**Complete Code** is available as node-cheat at [express_server_download_file](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/files/express_server_download_file), run `node app` followed by `npm install express mime`.